# Access to ExecutionContext

Tags: scala, akka, future

I have this trait

```
trait NonBlockingGoodness extends DataStore {
  import akka.dispatch.{ Future, ExecutionContext }
  import akka.util.duration._
  import akka.util.Timeout

  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(yourExecutorServiceGoesHere)
  implicit lazy val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)     
}
```

I would like to access the `ExecutionContext` in another trait like such

```
trait AsyncGoodness extends NonBlockingGoodness {
  import akka.dispatch.Future

  def doSomething = {
    Future { "Future is the bomb." }
  }
```

However, I am getting the error

```
Could not find implicit value for parameter executor: akka.dispatch.ExecutionContext
```

**UPDATED:**
I figured out how to get the `ExecutionContext` in scope

```
trait AsyncGoodness extends NonBlockingGoodness {
  import akka.dispatch.ExecutionContext
  import akka.dispatch.Future

  def doSomething()(implicit executor: ExecutionContext) = {
    Future { "Future is the bomb." }
  }
```

However, I have a follow-up question. Since I may have more than 1 method in `AsyncGoodness` that uses `ExecutionContext`, is there a way to pass it in at the `trait` level instead of at each method like I did above.

Comment: Just a passing remark: your name NonBlockingGoodness implies that all blocking is badness. This is a common belief these days but is a little naive: non-blocking IO can be worse than blocking IO in some cases. Other issues, such as having excess parallelism and having (or not having) well-tuned thread pools and even avoiding the trap of Amdahl's Law must be taken into consideration. Here's a case history: http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/blog/dispatch-http-critique

Comment: Is it enough that being non-blocking is goodness in the context where he's using it? Or did you consider that the name merely means that this trait does some goodness, and just happens to do it non-blockingly? What is this, Tumblr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, all I need to do is explicitly specify `ec` return type for the compiler to use it. Here's the working code

```
trait NonBlockingGoodness extends DataStore {
  import akka.dispatch.{ Future, ExecutionContext }
  import akka.util.duration._
  import akka.util.Timeout

  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(yourExecutorServiceGoesHere)
  implicit lazy val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)     
}

trait AsyncGoodness extends NonBlockingGoodness {
  import akka.dispatch.Future

  def doSomething = {
    Future { "Future is the bomb." }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you'd rather not have to import anything extra, but something like this should work for you.

```
trait NonBlockingGoodness {
  import scala.concurrent.{ Future, ExecutionContext }
  import scala.concurrent.util.duration._
  import akka.util.Timeout

  object Implicit {
     implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
     implicit lazy val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  }

}

trait AsyncGoodness extends NonBlockingGoodness {
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import Implicit._
  def doSomething = {
    Future { "Future is the bomb." }
  }
}
```

Comment: Bob seems to be on Akka2.0, but your answer is only valid for Scala2.10.

Comment: I know my import statements dont match what he would use.  But I thought the basic concept of "object Implicit {}" and "import Implicit._" works in Scala 2.9.

Comment: yes, the technique works for both versions, I just wanted to point out this deviation in the details.